# Revisiting beginner problem: Bank account

Tags: c#, console

I've been writing c# for about 4-5 years now mostly at school/uni. I consider it my most fluent language, but I am always learning. I decided to re-try a beginner project with the skills I've learned over the years - [kata style](https://medium.com/hackernoon/what-are-code-katas-and-why-should-we-care-2e3f1b7e111c).

The task is to make a simple bank account object which can take deposits and withdrawals and list the current balance.

#### Program.cs

```cs
namespace BankAccount;

static class Program
{
    private static readonly BankAccount BankAccount = new();

    private static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            BankAccount.WriteBalance();
            Console.WriteLine("Deposit (d), Withdraw(w), List Transactions (l), Quit (q)");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (input)
            {
                case "d": Deposit(); break;
                case "w": Withdraw(); break;
                case "l": BankAccount.ListTransactions(); break;
                case "q": goto Exit;
                default: Console.WriteLine("unknown command"); break;
            }
        } 
    Exit:;
    }

    private static void Withdraw()
    {
        if (GetAmount("Withdrawn") is {} amount)
            BankAccount.Withdraw(amount);
    }

    private static void Deposit()
    {
        if (GetAmount("Deposit") is {} amount)
            BankAccount.Deposit(amount);
    }

    private static decimal? GetAmount(string transactionVerb)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Amount to {transactionVerb}?");

        if (decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine()!, out var amount))
            return amount;

        Console.WriteLine("invalid quantity");
        return null;
    }

}
```

#### BankAccount.cs

```cs
namespace BankAccount;

internal class BankAccount
{
    private readonly IAppendOnlyList<Transaction> transactions = new AppendOnlyList<Transaction>();

    public decimal Balance => transactions.Sum(t => t.Amount);

    public void Deposit(decimal amount) => transactions.Add(new Deposit(amount));
    public void Withdraw(decimal amount) => transactions.Add(new Withdrawal(amount));

    public void WriteBalance()
        => Console.WriteLine($"Balance: {Balance:C}");

    public void ListTransactions()
    {
        foreach (var transaction in transactions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{transaction}");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Transaction.cs

```cs
namespace BankAccount;

internal abstract record Transaction(decimal Amount)
{
    public DateTime Time { get; } = DateTime.Now;
    public decimal Amount { get; } = Amount;
}

internal record Deposit(decimal Amount) : Transaction(Amount);

internal record Withdrawal(decimal Amount) : Transaction(-Amount);
```

#### AppendOnlyList.cs

```cs
using System.Collections;

namespace BankAccount;

internal interface IAppendOnlyList<T> : IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    void Add(T item);
}

internal class AppendOnlyList<T> : IAppendOnlyList<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> list = new();

    public void Add(T item)
        => list.Add(item);

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        => list.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => GetEnumerator();

    public int Count => list.Count;
    public T this[int index] => list[index];
}
```

I'd love to hear any feedback on the design / implementation of this solution, coding style, etc. Any improvement suggestions welcome, I'm trying to improve my c# and coding skills in general.

Comment: Why don't you use [`Environment.Exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=net-8.0) instead of `goto Exit` and `Exit:;`?

Comment: BTW which C# version are you using?

Comment: "Withdrawn" isn't an action, it's the past participle of "withdraw". You forgot a space: "Withdraw(w)".

Answer (score 3):

If you find yourself writing `Console.WriteLine` in a domain class, you need to stop. What happens if you try to use `BankAccount` in a context where there is no standard io? Two of its methods become useless:

```
public void WriteBalance()
    => Console.WriteLine($"Balance: {Balance:C}");

public void ListTransactions()
{
    foreach (var transaction in transactions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{transaction}");
    }
}
```

Instead, you should return the output as data and allow the caller to display it in a sensible way:

```
public void WriteBalance() => $"Balance: {Balance:C}";

public IEnumerable<string> ListTransactions() => transactions.Select(t => t.ToString());
```

It can be a good idea to create separate types for `Deposit` and `Withdrawal` but only if you're going to use that power to validate the inputs. As written, I can create a negative `Deposit` and a positive `Withdrawal`.

Good approach to store a list of transactions and query for the current balance. I'm not sure the `AppendOnlyList` is really worth it as it doesn't form part of the public interface. As it is a private field, I'd just store an `ICollection<Transaction>`.